# How do I set Full Text on MySQL Workbench?

Tags: innodb, mysql-workbench, full-text-search

I'm trying to set the Full Text property for some columns within a table in a `MySQL InnoDB` database.

I can't find the option on MySQL Workbench and I've tried various searches on Google to find out how but I couldn't find anything.

These are my current options:

```
PK  = Primary Key
NN  = Not Null
UQ  = Unique Key
BIN = Binary
UN  = Unsigned
ZF  = Zero Filled
AI  = Auto Increment
```

[image: MW Screenshot of property options]

Where can I find the `Full Text` option on MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FULLTEXT is an index type, not a column attribute. When you create an index you can select any of INDEX, UNIQUE, FULLTEXT and PRIMARY types. See the table editor, on the "Index" tab.

[image]

Comment: I thought of that but somehow I don't see `FULLTEXT` index type :-/ I'm using Workbench 6.0

Comment: I don't see FULLTEXT index type when creating an index with InnoDB. Although as of today, InnoDB supports it. Latest WB6.3. Anybody knows what's going on?

Comment: I added a screenshot to show you where to find the FULLTEXT index type.

Comment: Indexes is on the tab after Columns just below the Columns box.

Answer (score 1):

Double click your table then you go to Indexes Tab. There you can modify indexes.

For newer version of MySQL Workbench please note that FULLTEXT on InnoDB only available when you choose Target MySQL Version 8 on Model > Model Options.